# PHPStorm does not show classname anymore

Tags: settings, phpstorm

I've imported wrong settings to my PHPstorm and I've lost possibility to see where am I
[image]

Anybody knows what setting responsible for displaying that line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | General | Appearance | Show HTML breadcrumbs**

You need to re-open editor tab to see the changes.

Comment: great!!! thanks man, I've spent almost hour to search where it is :) thank you too much. Maybe you know also how to get back something line which show beginning and ending of piece of code ? (class, method, function etc..)??

Comment: `Show method separators`

Comment: yeah this option were enabled but now I understand that the problem in color and not in separator itself. Thanks, man.